# Integrate segment.io in App

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate **segment.io** in my app so that I can send by analytics data to `Google Analytics` through segment. I have read the official documentation to integrate segment but didn't understand much and also there are also very less documentation or sample example available on internet.

If anyone can guide me how to integrate segment in my app, then it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just excavating this as I recently did something similar.

Segment now provides a very detailed documentation on how to integrate your android app using segment's android library. Please check out:

https://segment.com/docs/sources/mobile/android/

Hope you were able to do it at the time.